Flutter, mask_text_input_formatter where symbols are replaced
I am wondering if there is a way to extend somehow MaskTextInputFormatter class where instead of inserting symbols while typing they will be replaced, and there is no way to remove them, only replace, hence fixed text length. For example: initial value is 01-20>00 , and say cursor is at the position 0, and I type 5, the result will be 51-20>00.
I tried to extend the MaskTextInputFormatter, got it working with some simple masks, but with more complex ones it becomes complicated. And it seems to me that, there is a simpler solution. Also tried to chain input formatters, got something working but not reliable.
Would be greatfull for any ideas, or solutions.
Thanks,
Andy

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
